# Java get key listener to listen to frame

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

Main Class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display("Graphic Window","icon.gif",800,600,true,false,2,60);
    }
}
```

Top of display class

```
public class Display extends Frame {
```

Keyboard class

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

//.addKeyListener();
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
    System.out.println("Pressed "+key);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    System.out.println("Released "+key);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
    System.out.println("Typed "+key);
}
}
```

I Can't figure out how to get key listener to listen to the frame because I want to have keyboard be its own class and then have another class that gets what keys are being pressed and do actions like move based off that.

Comment: Note: You shouldn't name your own class `Window`. There's already a [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) in AWT.

Comment: I Called it window because I'm not a fan of the term frame and window is the generic term. So I'd have to think of what else to call it. Renamed to Display.

Comment: Join us in the 3rd millennium & use Swing (e.g. `JFrame`).  With Swing, use key-bindings.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new Display(.....).addKeyListener(new Keyboard);
```

Comment: [Current Code](http://screensnapr.com/e/OkM4qE.jpg) It doesn't like it works like that atm, as well I'm trying to keep as much code out of the main, so like I will end up with Main, Display, Keyboard, Character (for example) and character will get MoveUp from keyboard.